Vite build freezes randomly
I am developing a React App with Typescript and Vite.
At some point it started happening that running the command "vite build" which builds the project randomly freezes, i.e. nothing is happening, no error, it just stops. No additional info with verbose debugging either.
I first noticed it because when launching the project from vs code the page wouldn't load and now I tracked it down to the build process freezing.
I don't think it's related to the code because it also happens on a brand new vite project created with vite@latest, although much more rarely. Tried an older project that hasn't been touched for a while and worked perfectly before, same problem.
In my gitlab ci it has never happened.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Tried removing packages, debugging, deleting cache, increasing memory
Nothing changed
Found a few other questions regarding a similar issue but the solutions always have been related to code or packages. I checked and tried those things but it didn't help. Also it seems like for those question it was always happening, for me it happens most of the time
To try to replicate the issue you can create a new vite project with "npm create vite@latest {name} -- --template react-ts". Replace name.
Install the packages with npm install.
Then build the project with npm run build, which is defined in package.json.
Eventually (like once in 20 times) it will happen that a build freezes, which might look like this.

It was a company antivirus software related issue.
Uninstalling solved it.
